# How to edit JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
global $obj;
global $books;
global $chapters;
global $verses;
global $newObj;

 $json = file_get_contents("json/jsoneng.json");
 $obj = json_decode($json, true);

 foreach($obj['books'] as $books){
     foreach ($books['chapters'] as $chapters){
         foreach($chapters['verses'] as $verses){

             echo $verses['text'] . "<br/>";
              $verses['text'] = "";      
            }
     }
 }


 $newObj = json_encode($obj);
 file_put_contents('json/what.json', $newObj);

?>
```

And this is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "book": "1 Nephi",
            "chapters": [
                {
                    "chapter": 1,
                    "reference": "1 Nephi 1",
                    "verses": [
                        {
                            "reference": "1 Nephi 1:1",
                            "text": "I, Nephi, having been born of goodly parents, therefore I was taught somewhat in all the learning of my father; and having seen many afflictions in the course of my days, nevertheless, having been highly favored of the Lord in all my days; yea, having had a great knowledge of the goodness and the mysteries of God, therefore I make a record of my proceedings in my days.",
                            "verse": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "reference": "1 Nephi 1:2",
                            "text": "Yea, I make a record in the language of my father, which consists of the learning of the Jews and the language of the Egyptians.",
                            "verse": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "reference": "1 Nephi 1:3",
                            "text": "And I know that the record which I make is true; and I make it with mine own hand; and I make it according to my knowledge.",
                            "verse": 3
                        },
```

............................................

I want to delete the whole text and make it empty like
"text": "",

But my code is not working it is saving the same original json file.

Comment: Don't you think, that the problem in that you are json_encoding **$obj** as its value has not been changed?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the pass by reference with ampersand

```
foreach($chapters['verses'] as &$verses){
   $verses['text'] = "";      
}
```

Your code should be :-

```
foreach($obj['books'] as &$books){
   foreach ($books['chapters'] as &$chapters){
     foreach($chapters['verses'] as &$verses){
          $verses['text'] = "";      
        }
   }
 }
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/DC9p6)

Comment: You need to pass references in each `foreach` assignment, otherwise you'll never be making changes to the top-level object. See the other answer

Comment: @Phil thanks for pointing that out, i was forget to put it, solution has been updated.

Comment: @Phil great observation.

Comment: @AlivetoDie ..:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [passing by reference concept of php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

***Case 1:*** If the json structure will always same in each case, then

```
foreach($obj['books'][0]['chapters'][0]['verses'] as &$verses){//& => passing by reference concept
  $verses['text'] = '';
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/sOEuV

***Case 2:*** If json structure can change, then

```
foreach($obj['books'] as &$books){
     foreach ($books['chapters'] as &$chapters){
         foreach($chapters['verses'] as &$verses){ //& => passing by reference concept
            $verses['text'] = "";      
         }
     }
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/1Uv5Y